# Test functions apps set up using Azure DevOps pipelines

Tags: azure, function, azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-pipelines

I have many functions apps I have set up and I have my pipelines set up for them but I'd like to know is there any efficient way of how to test the functionality of each function? That way I know it has been successful as pipelines dont always give a true indication it has been successfully deployed. My function apps all vary to what they are set up to do but would like some guidance on an effective method of testing them. I have included how one of my pipelines is currently set up and checks out but at same time Im looking to see how to go about testing this.

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

trigger:
 branches:
  include:
   - dev
 paths:
  include:
   - BridgeExport/*

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'release'

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: Set .NET 6.x
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.x'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run - dotnet restore
  inputs:
    command: restore
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    vstsFeed: '39b14414-e819-472c-a8c9-e1b150e85a52/1e69f816-5f54-4793-9746-2a8eed83160b'
    projects: '**/BridgeExport/*.csproj'
    includeNuGetOrg: true
    modifyOutputPath: true
    noCache: true

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run - dotnet build
  inputs:
    command: 'build'
    projects: '**/BridgeExport/*.csproj'
    zipAfterPublish: true
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
 
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Run - dotnet publish
  inputs:
    command: publish
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output publish_output --no-restore'
    publishWebProjects: false
    modifyOutputPath: false
    zipAfterPublish: false
    workingDirectory: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/BridgeExport'

- task: ArchiveFiles@2
  displayName: "Archive files"
  inputs:
    rootFolderOrFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/BridgeExport/publish_output"
    includeRootFolder: false
    archiveFile: "$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildNumber).zip"

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: Export Artifacts
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/build$(Build.BuildNumber).zip'
    artifactName: 'drop_$(Build.BuildNumber)_$(Build.SourceBranchName)'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to test your dotnet function apps. One of the most common ways is to write `unit tests`. Unit tests ensure that individual components of the application work as expected. Assertions test the component API.

Another way to test your dotnet function apps is to write `integration tests`. Integration tests ensure that component interactions work as expected against external artifacts like databases. Assertions can test component API, UI, or the side effects of actions like database I/O, logging, etc.

You can also write `functional tests` for each function. Functional tests ensure that the application works as expected from the user’s perspective.

Lastly, you can write `service tests`. Service tests ensure that end-to-end service use cases, including testing multiple services at the same time, are tested.

To run these tests, you can use the `dotnet test` command. This command runs all the tests in the specified project. You can check the sample in [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/dotnet-core?view=azure-devops&tabs=dotnetfive#run-your-tests) for the details.

```
steps:
# ...
# do this after other tasks such as building
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Tests/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'
```

You can also use [VSTest@2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vstest-v2?view=azure-pipelines) task to run functional tests in Azure Pipelines. This task can be used to run Selenium UI tests, a form of functional testing.
[image]

```
  - task: VSTest@2
    displayName: Test Assemblies
    inputs:
      testSelector: 'testAssemblies'
      testAssemblyVer2: '**\$(BuildConfiguration)\test\*.dll'
      searchFolder: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
      codeCoverageEnabled: true
      platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
      configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```